# ISO8601 to epoch milliseconds

Tags: android, kotlin, epoch, iso8601

I'm parsing my ISO8601 string format to milliseconds, so far I'm having an error

**also is there a better way because it requires API 26**

`Text '2019-02-15T00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 19`

```
        val millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli()
        println("EPOCH $millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think I understand the question, but it would be clearer if you could please add [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question (use the edit link under the line of tags).

Answer (score 1):

### Your error

Your string gives us a date (2019-02-15) and a time of day (00:00:00). It doesn’t give us any time zone or UTC offset. Without either of the latter we cannot know a unique point in time, which is required for converting to milliseconds since the epoch. If you know the time zone implied in your date-time string you may convert like the following. I am sorry that I can write only Java code.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/St_Barthelemy");
    String dateTimeText = "2019-02-15T00:00:00";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeText);
    long millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch = dateTime.atZone(zone)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println("EPOCH " + millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch);
```

Now output is:

> EPOCH 1550203200000

Substitute your time zone if it didn’t happen to be America/St_Barthelemy. A `LocalDateTime` is a date and time witout tme zone or offset, so this class parses your string without error. Next we use the known time zone for converting.

**Your exception message** said:

> `Text '2019-02-15T00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 19`

Index 19 is the end of your string, so the error message says that something was missing there. Assuming that you were using `Instant.parse()` (your question doesn’t tell), @Lenin is correct in the other answer that `Instant.parse()` expects that the parsed string ends in `Z` for “Zulu time zone” or UTC or offset zero.

### … it requires API 26

The good news is that it does *not* require API level 26. `Instant` and the other classes we’ve been using belong to java.time, the modern Java date and time API. This API has been backported.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, or Android 8.0 and later) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On Android earlier than API level 26 (Android 8.0) use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the format at the end. Try '2019-02-15T00:00:00Z'. The Z means Zulu time which is +0 Offset

Comment: Yes, if we know that the string is in Zulu time/offset +00:00. I don’t know whether it is.